# How to force Firefox to open MP3 files with a given application?

Tags: firefox

I routinely have trouble getting Firefox to open MP3 files in an application on my Windows 7 laptop. When I visit an MP3 URL ([sample link from *A Prairie Home Companion*](http://download.publicradio.org/podcast/nflw/2015/11/21/aphc_20151121_mel_128.mp3)), I get the following dialog box:

[image: Open file dialog screenshot]

I have Windows Media Player set as the default MP3 file handler in Windows, and I also have the **Do this automatically for files like this from now on** option selected. Regardless, this dialog *always* opens up. I even have the application set in Firefox's *Options > Applications* area:

[image: Application setting]

Is there a way I can force Firefox to open MP3s in the application of my choice, without getting this stupid dialog?

Comment: Have you tried Preferences -> Applications and configuration of filtered mp3 settings?

Comment: Yes, I have that setting set in Firefox. I've added an additional screenshot showing this.

Comment: So try InlineDisposition https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inlinedisposition/

Answer (score 0):

As Firefox chooses configuration of a hosting servers over user preferences `Preferences -> Applications -> Content Type Actions` (`about:preferences#applications`) - a hosting server could force the download of a file (HTTP Content-Disposition header: disposition-type = "attachment") even when you prefer other action.

[InlineDisposition](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inlinedisposition/) Firefox extension could help to avoids this situation by `changing the disposition of Content-Disposition response headers from attachment to inline`.